# Computing a revenue for VCG auction

Tags: game-theory, economics, auction-theory

I would like your help with the following question regarding computing a revenue for a seller of an VCG (vickrey clarke groves) auction, I'm really new to this auctions\game theory so I'd really appreciate an explanation.

The auction is as follows: Three bidders,one item. each bidder has a valuation out of a uniform distribution $[0,1]$.  How do I calculate the revenue of such auction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a single item, the VCG payment rule is just that the winner pays the second-highest bid*. So the expected revenue is the expected second-highest bid. As noted at [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous)#Order_statistics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_%28continuous%29#Order_statistics) , for $3$ bidders distributed uniformly and independently on $[0,1]$, this is $0.5$.

* (Edit) perhaps it is helpful to explain this. If the winner were not in the auction, the total utility of the remaining bidders would be the second-highest bid, since that bidder would get the item and gain that utility. If the winner *is* in the auction, the total utility of the remaining bidders would be zero because the item goes to the winner. So the difference in welfare is the second-highest bid, so this is what the winner must pay.